# compare two tables having same column name but different date column names

Tags: mysql, sql, r, join, databricks

I have table A

| id1 | dt |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | 2022-04-10 |
| a2 | 2022-04-10 |
| a1 | 2022-04-10 |
| x1 | 2022-05-10 |
| x2 | 2022-04-10 |
| y2 | 2022-04-10 |
| y1 | 2022-05-10 |
| x1 | 2022-06 -10 |

Table B

| id1 | dt |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 2022-04-10 |
| c3 | 2022-04-10 |
| a1 | 2022-05-10 |
| l1 | 2022-05-10 |
| b1 | 2022-04-10 |
| y2 | 2022-04-10 |
| x1 | 2022-06-10 |
| z1 | 2022-05-10 |

Note: A and B has date values but different column names ( 'dt' for Table A and 'date' for table B)

Desired output:

| id1 | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | 2022-04-10 |
| a2 | 2022-04-10 |
| x2 | 2022-04-10 |

**Update 1:**
note:
1)y2,a1 are not in Desired output because they exists in both tables
2)c3 is not in desired output because it exists in Table B

**id1 exists in both tables, but i want "id1" values only from Table A which are not in Table B for the date 2022-04-10.**

steps taken so far:
`select id1 from A where dt="2022-04-10" EXCEPT select id1 from B`
result ( its running for a long time and timing out, not sure its because of Volume of Data or the query is wrong) will check with smaller tables.

I can't use Left Inner Join because Date columns are different ( date vs dt).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please check c3?  Should that not be in your desired output?

Comment: `a1 2022-04-10`, `c3 2022-04-10`, `b1 2022-04-10` from tableB should be expected to be found in the output as long as those ids are present in tableB but not in tableA (with respect your `and Vice Versa` requirement), am I missing something ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked as well

```
with A as (
select distinct id1
from Table_A
where dt = '2022-04-10'
)

, B as (
select distinct id1
from  Table_B
where date = '2022-04-10')

select id1 from A
where id1 not in (select id1 from B)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure of your output. But I think you want something like this:

```
bind_rows(
  anti_join(rename(a,date=dt) %>% filter(date=="2022-04-10"),b %>% filter(date=="2022-04-10")),
  anti_join(b %>% filter(date=="2022-04-10"),rename(a,date=dt) %>% filter(date=="2022-04-10"))
)
```

Output:

```
   id1       date
1:  x1 2022-04-10
2:  a2 2022-04-10
3:  x2 2022-04-10
4:  y2 2022-04-10
5:  a1 2022-04-10
6:  c3 2022-04-10
7:  b1 2022-04-10
```

Comment: sorry my question was not clear, I have updated now,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by applying a `UNION` statement between a left joined and a right joined table. From these joins your targets are those rows whose second table values is NULL because of no match:

```
SELECT tableA.id1,
       tableA.dt
FROM      tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB
       ON tableA.id1 = tableB.id1 
      AND tableA.dt = tableB.dt
WHERE tableB.id1 IS NULL
  AND tableA.dt = '2022-04-10' 

UNION 

SELECT tableB.id1,
       tableB.dt
FROM      tableB 
LEFT JOIN tableA
       ON tableB.id1 = tableA.id1 
      AND tableB.dt = tableA.dt
WHERE tableA.id1 IS NULL
  AND tableB.dt = '2022-04-10'
```

Find the SQL Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6DgaJSRrjSB8XfZaEdkdNA/0).

---

**EDIT**

Want results only from table A:

```
SELECT tableA.id1,
       tableA.dt
FROM      tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB
       ON tableA.id1 = tableB.id1 
      AND tableA.dt = tableB.dt
WHERE tableB.id1 IS NULL
  AND tableA.dt = '2022-04-10'
```

Only from table B?

```
SELECT tableB.id1,
       tableB.dt
FROM      tableB 
LEFT JOIN tableA
       ON tableB.id1 = tableA.id1 
      AND tableB.dt = tableA.dt
WHERE tableA.id1 IS NULL
  AND tableB.dt = '2022-04-10'
```

Comment: really appreciate.
but i see results from both tables. Is there a way i get results only from Table A?

Comment: You can just use the first part without the union if you want only results from `tableA`, viceversa use only the second part without the union if you want only results from `tableB`.

Comment: works perfect, Table A has "dt" as column name for date, but it still works.